# ImageView animation help

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I'm trying to figure out how to animate in and out of `Imageviews`.

Basically I have a `LinearLayou`t with an `ImageView` and a `Button` at the bottom. Everytime the button is pressed, `onClick()` is invoked and I do

```
image.setImageResource(imageArray[imageCounter]);
```

I simply change the image displayed on the `ImageView` by selecting different photos in the @drawable. 
Now I want to put an animation when these imageviews are changed (when button pressed). I used

```
inAnimation = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this,true);
```

and in onClick() I do

```
image.setImageResource(imageArray[imageCounter]); 
  image.startAnimation(inAnimation);
```

This works fine too. The new image comes to the screen animated. But how can put an **out** animation too? It seems only one animation can be assigned with  startAnimation().

What is the best way to animate an imageview OUT and then animate another imageview IN?
Because I want to change the animation depending on the button pressed, I cannot use ViewFlipper. For example, if I press button_Anim1, current image will slideout from right and the new image will fade in. But if I press button_Anim2, current image will slideout from top and the new image will slidein from left. And so on.

I see that I cannot use two different
`image.startAnimation()` in the `onClick()` method to make the current image `View.INVISIBLE` and then make the new image `View.VISIBLE`.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Use ImageSwitcher instead of ImageView and look at the ImageSwitcher example in ApiDemos (using a gallery)

Comment: Thank you very much Sameer. ImageSwitcher can do exactly what I want. Cheers.